# cookies not saving when using express-session

Tags: reactjs, express, mern, express-session

I am using express-session to save cookies into my browser so I can use it for authentication. I am sending a post request from my frontend (React) using axios to the backend and use User.register to save the new user to the database(mongodb)

I am able to save the user to my database however, there are no cookies being saved in my browser.

Frontend post request using axios:

[image]

backend post request handler

[image]

Comment: Are they both running on the same port?

Comment: no. frontend is running on port 3000 and backend is on port 3001. I have a proxy of http://localhost:3001 in my frontend package.json

Comment: This may be the issue, as a session will not be shared by default across different ports, there are ways to configure that though.

Comment: Is there a work around for that?

Comment: Yes, you could configure it to work across domains/ports but I haven't done it before so I honestly don't know how the configuration works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your server add this code

```
  app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: "http://localhost:3000" }));
```

Client axios config

```
  const Axios= axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:3001/",
    withCredentials: true,
});
```